# refresh single cell in yui datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable, yui

I am using a yui datatable to show tabular data with certain fields that update in real timee.  All examples I've seen require that the entire table be re-drawn even if only one column of data has been changed.  Obviously this causes problems with both client-side sorting and scrolling and adversely affects UI performance as well.  Is there any way to have a datable render ONLY the cells for which data was updated?

Comment: but if one cell was updated it should be resorted again. Otherwise order of rows will be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`DataTable.updateCell`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.DataTable.html#method_updateCell) method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm using the onDataReturnSetRows to update the recordset attached to the table and then looping through the recordset and running updateCell on only the cells that I want to refresh.  Unfortunately, it looks like the recordset is not actually being updated by the onDateReturnSetRows call.  Am I missing something really simple again?